# Using the same ssh keys for multiple Vagrant machines

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I'm trying to set up two VMs with Vagrant, and one of them needs to be able to ssh into the second one using the private key.

I defined both VMs inside one vagrantfile, started them up and then copied the private key from the .vagrant directory into my first VM. I was then able to ssh into the second VM without a password.

The problem is that this is not stable, Vagrant recycles this key each time I do `vagrant up` and creates a new one. This obviously breaks the ability to ssh from the first VM to the second one until I copy the private key again.

I don't particularly care which key exactly Vagrant uses, I just want it to be stable so that I can always ssh between my VMs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possibility to do that :

1. have a shell provisioner to run every time you boot the VM to copy the new generated key, so basically every time you run `vagrant up` you will copy the ssh key into the VM so you will still be able to ssh into the second VM.
2. force vagrant to use a key, add the following parameter to your Vagrantfile where you will store your own custom key

   ```
   config.ssh.private_key_path = "custom_key_file"
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
   ```

so Vagrant will use this key file when it boots the VM and you can copy this key into your VM to ssh into the second

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I supply the corresponding public key with option 2?

Comment: you can enable `config.ssh.forward_agent`